# no response in browser after npm start successfully

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, nodes

i have added a new module to my application and trying to run application, i am not getting any error while compilation nor in the console but the browser is not responding .

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ucps-online-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.6",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.6.3",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "primeng": "4.1.0",
    "ng2-datetime-picker": "0.12.9",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.3",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-datepicker": "1.8.3",
    "ng2-pagination": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.6"
  }
,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@types/node": "7.0.48",
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.3",
    "codelyzer": "2.1.1",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.8.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.1"
  }
,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.9.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

[brower not responing and console has no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tng6.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the index.html file in your codebase?

Comment: This is my index.html file :                                                                   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ucps-online-client</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `<app-root>Loading...</app-root> </body>` in your html file.So you should be define the path routes.

please refer the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)